# T test assumptions

Tags: t-test, assumptions

I'm performing a t-test on a time series with a sliding window (i.e. every N samples, perform a t test).

I know that overall, the samples are roughly normally distributed, however adjacent samples are correlated, so the N samples (taken for the t test) may not be normally distributed. Are the t test assumptions violated in this case?

Comment: The correlation will stuff up the variance of the mean; this may be *much* be more important than the issue of non-normality (because it doesn't go away with increasing sample size).

Answer (score 1):

it's not clear what t-test you're running, but it's clear that the assumptions are violated. the samples are heavily correlated when you overlap them.